# Safari giving precedence to installed font

Tags: css, macos, google-chrome, fonts, safari

Some of the designers working at my workplace noticed that on Safari the font of our website appeared to be the one installed on their machine and not the one we are serving.

We noticed it in two different occasions and with two different fonts: Montserrat and Open Sans.

The first time (with Montserrat) the user had a newer version of the font, and she saw the newest only on Safari, because she had installed it on her local machine (this wasn't happening on Chrome).

The second time (with Open Sans) we saw a bolder font only on a particular machine: we then discovered that on that machine the user had installed a bolder weight (700) than the one we were serving (600). And the rule was

```
font-weight: bold;
```

so I suppose that the browser picked up the boldest (700) from the installed fonts.

I did some research but didn't find any evidence of this. Does anyone know if there is any evidence/documentation on Safari giving precedence to installed fonts instead of the ones you are serving?

We are not using Google Fonts from Google's CDN, as we decided to download them and serve them from our own server.

EDIT: I'm adding the code we use to load the font (generated using [Google Webfonts Helper](https://google-webfonts-helper.herokuapp.com/fonts)):

```
@font-face {
  font-family: 'Open Sans';
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 400;
  src: url("font/opensans/open-sans-latin_cyrillic-400.eot");
  src: local("Open Sans"), local("OpenSans"), url("font/opensans/open-sans-latin_cyrillic-400.eot?#iefix") format("embedded-opentype"), url("font/opensans/open-sans-latin_cyrillic-400.woff2") format("woff2"), url("font/opensans/open-sans-latin_cyrillic-400.woff") format("woff"), url("font/opensans/open-sans-latin_cyrillic-400.ttf") format("truetype"), url("font/opensans/open-sans-latin_cyrillic-400.svg#OpenSans") format("svg"); 
}
@font-face {
  font-family: 'Open Sans';
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 600;
  src: url("font/opensans/open-sans-latin_cyrillic-600.eot");
  src: local("Open Sans Semibold"), local("OpenSans-Semibold"), url("font/opensans/open-sans-latin_cyrillic-600.eot?#iefix") format("embedded-opentype"), url("font/opensans/open-sans-latin_cyrillic-600.woff2") format("woff2"), url("font/opensans/open-sans-latin_cyrillic-600.woff") format("woff"), url("font/opensans/open-sans-latin_cyrillic-600.ttf") format("truetype"), url("font/opensans/open-sans-latin_cyrillic-600.svg#OpenSans") format("svg"); 
}

@font-face {
  font-family: 'Montserrat';
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 400;
  src: url("font/montserrat/montserrat-latin-regular.eot");
  src: local("Montserrat-Regular"), url("font/montserrat/montserrat-latin-regular.eot?#iefix") format("embedded-opentype"), url("font/montserrat/montserrat-latin-regular.woff2") format("woff2"), url("font/montserrat/montserrat-latin-regular.woff") format("woff"), url("font/montserrat/montserrat-latin-regular.ttf") format("truetype"), url("font/montserrat/montserrat-latin-regular.svg#Montserrat") format("svg"); 
}
@font-face {
  font-family: 'Montserrat';
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 700;
  src: url("font/montserrat/montserrat-latin-700.eot");
  src: local("Montserrat-Bold"), url("font/montserrat/montserrat-latin-700.eot?#iefix") format("embedded-opentype"), url("font/montserrat/montserrat-latin-700.woff2") format("woff2"), url("font/montserrat/montserrat-latin-700.woff") format("woff"), url("font/montserrat/montserrat-latin-700.ttf") format("truetype"), url("font/montserrat/montserrat-latin-700.svg#Montserrat") format("svg"); 
}
```

And the relevant code to give a different font-face to different parts of the pages.

```
body{
    font-family: "Open Sans", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
    font-size: 14px;
}

h6, h5, h4, h3, h2, h1{
    font-family: inherit; // inheriting from body
    font-weight: bold;
}

.view{
    font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
}
```

Comment: This sounds like a question with code, but there is no code shown... so: I assume you're using `@font-face` *without* a `local` source because you never, ever, want any installed copy to win because you have no guarantee that it's the exact version your content was made to work with.

Comment: As @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans pointed I didn't post the relevant code, so I edited it to show the relevant portions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the code you show the solution is kind of obvious: if you don't want local fonts to interfere, don't tell the browser to try `local()` first. Or at all, really.

It's 2017, and in today's browser landscape you *only* want `src: url(woff font version) format("woff")`, nothing else: no other formats, no local-first, just explicitly the font your content should use. In the current browser landscape `eot` and `svg` don't even exist as valid formats anymore, and woff *are* ttf/otf, but with compression, and marked explicitly as intended "for the web" so that some normally required data can be left off, yielding an even smaller font payload. The *only* other format you might add is WOFF2, which uses a newer compression algorithm and allows "slicing" up a single font into several subsets so that the browser only loads the slices it needs to style your content instead of an entire font in one go.

Whatever generated this CSS for you appears to still be stuck in "how webfonts worked in 2012".

Comment: Ok so I just need to remove the "local" specification to ensure that no local font gets rendered. I thought this generated code was kind of standard so didn't touch it (apart from the src folder). Anyway I still don't understand why the local font gets rendered in Safari and not in Chrome.

Comment: It used to be, but with every browser maker having "caught up" on webfont standards, that source collection (with local, eot, svg, and ttf/otf) does more harm than good these days. The reason browsers do different things with local() is that they prioritise differentely. As for why different browsers do different things: Chrome's dev team has a very different idea of what standard behaviour should be compared to Safari. To the degree that they forked webkit, renamed it to blink, and then started doing their own thing.

Comment: Actually removing the local specification to our font-face didn't fix the issue. [Here](https://codepen.io/giorgiotempesta/pen/RgoWbJ) is a pen showing how installing the font on your local machine still affects the rendering on Safari. We are thinking about replacing all occurrences of `font-weight: bold` with `font-weight: 600` for the Open Sans font.

Comment: if installing the font on your local machine still affects it, then either your CSS is not getting respected, or you found a genuine bug in Safari that you should file. But the codepen you show does *not* load the font as webfont in the slightest, it is literally going with "whatever is locally installed with the name Open Sans". **Use a webfont if you need to control the font**, so use an `@font-face` rule that loads the font, explicitly, from a url, with the weight and style explicitly stated for that url.

Comment: @GiorgioTempesta not sure why you unflagged this as correct: you *really do* need to use `@font-face`, and *really* without a `local()` source. And that *really does* solve your problem. The codepen you gave in your comment here does *not* use `@font-face` and so will quite obviously fail to do the right thing because you're telling the browser to use the system font if available

Comment: I'm sorry I didn't state that explicitly: I was including the `@font-face` rule as "External CSS" (from the Settings of CSS Tab), now I am including it with the `@import` rule for clarity. I'm beginning to think this is a bug in Safari.

Comment: Ok, my codepen is not working 'cause the file I'm importing is not over https. I have moved the whole example [here](http://gtempesta.io/font-face-styles/).

Comment: omg why are you using all these different formats? *Only* use `eot for IE8 and below, and use `woff` (or woff2) for *everything else* because everything else supports woff. No "#iefix" nonsense, no ttf, no svg, etc: keep the code minimal so you find your problem, and solve that problem first So: start with a font that is guaranteed to use the correct CSS first: `<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:400,600" rel="stylesheet">`, and then let's start with this. http://jsbin.com/lawabupino/edit?html,css,output

Comment: That jsbin, with chrome on the left, and safari on the right: http://i.imgur.com/uT0SxDd.png

Comment: Indeed, and it looks like this is caused by `font-weight:600` getting clobbered by Safari. Oddly, the web inspector claims that the `bold` declaration lives at the same depth as `600` and this is not even remotely true. However, there is a really simple solution: we can add a third font-face declaration for `font-family: "Open Sans"; src: url(semi bold font); font-weight: bold` and now anything that incorrectly uses `bold` or 700 will still use the semi-bold font instead.

Comment: also you should probably file this on the webkit issue tracker: specifying h1's font-weight yourself should win over the default browser weight.

Answer (score 0):

Eventually I used what @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans suggested in one of the last comments to his own answer, I'm posting it here just for clarity.

We removed every `local` specification and every `src` apart from the `.eot` file and the `.woff2` file.

Then we added this declaration to tell Safari that our bold font should render with the 600 weight, otherwise Safari would look into the installed copy of the font (which included the 700 weight).

```
@font-face {
   font-family: 'Open Sans';
   font-style: normal;
   font-weight: bold;
   src: url('font/open-sans-latin_cyrillic_latin-ext-600.eot'); /* IE9 Compat Modes */
   src: url('font/open-sans-latin_cyrillic_latin-ext-600.woff2') format('woff2'); /* Super Modern Browsers */
}
```

Comment: on a "making sure your code comments are correct" note: be mindful of the fact that if you're only offering woff2 as alternative, that `eot` source is "IE compat mode" (bearing in mind that Edge is not IE) because IE does not support woff2 in any version. If your alternative is woff (v1) then this would be IE8 compat mode, as IE9-IE11 come with support for woff.